# Unable to export tflite_ssd_graph in tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I trained the model using TensorFlow object detection API. It's working fine I am trying to export for low-end devices. I am unable to export it using.

```sh
python models/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py 
--input_type image_tensor 
--pipeline_config_path output/training/001/pipeline.config 
--trained_checkpoint_prefix output/training/001/ckpt-40 
--output_directory exported-models/tf_lite_inference_model add_postprocessing_op=true
```

it's showing an error.

```sh
    export_tflite_ssd_graph_lib.export_tflite_graph(
  File "C:\Users\inspiron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\export_tflite_ssd_graph_lib.py", line 241, in export_tflite_graph
    image = tf.placeholder(
  File "C:\Users\inspiron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 3176, in placeholder
    raise RuntimeError("tf.placeholder() is not compatible with "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by install tf-nightly.

```sh
python -m pip install tf-nightly
```

for more reference check the [Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9767) on Tensorflow Model Repo.